# No output for sum in c# program

Tags: c#

Could someone please have a look at this code and help me determine why I get no output for sum when the for loop is exited?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

/*This program finds 100 3 digit numbers between 100 and 1000, prints the message: "Cha, Cha, Cha!" after every 10th number, and outputs the sum of the numbers */

namespace MikeVertreeseRandom
{
    class RandomNumbers    //using the random class for number generation 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();

            int number = 0; //r.Next() finds the next random # bet 100 and 1000

            int sum = 0;  //declaring the variable "numberTotal" for the sum 

            int i = 1;            //i is the index counter

            for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)  //the program will run through 100 iterations
            {
                number = r.Next(100, 1000);

                Console.WriteLine(number); //program prints the next random #

                sum += number; //need to keep a running sum of the numbers found

                if ((i % 10) == 0)    //every 10th iteration, do something
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Cha, Cha, Cha!"); //prints this message every 10th number
               }
           }

           Console.WriteLine("The sum is: []", sum);
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: The opening curly brace of `class RandomNumbers {` is missing.

Comment: You initialize `i` twice. Instead, you should declare it in the for-loop itself (not before): `for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks Tim~~ the opening curly brace for 'class RandomNumbers' is on its own line. I'll keep in mind the proper initialization of the index variable (within the for-loop, instead of before). -m

Answer (score 7):

You are doing

```
Console.WriteLine("The sum is: []", sum);
```

Instead use `{n}`, where n is the nth parameter to `Console.WriteLine` after the format string, ie

```
Console.WriteLine("The sum is: {0}", sum);
```

See [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format) for more info on format strings.

Comment: That totally fixed it! I'm such a "noob":P! Thank you. Been staring at it for a while...

Comment: No problem!  Glad the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

In [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) the matching braces ("{" and "}") are required.